# How do iOS HTTP request retries work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, nsurlconnection

I'm using NSURLConnection to send an HTTP request and running it with

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];
```

where "self.request" is a configured NSMutableURLRequest object. Upon a network failure and callback to

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
```

I'd like to cancel the request and write the payload to file to be uploaded later. However if I reconnect too quickly the payload ends up getting sent still (and I later send the same payload from the file). In the failure callback, I've tried to use

```
[connection cancel];
```

But the http request still goes through upon reconnecting within a few seconds. Is this due to some retry mechanic that I can disable?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs on `didFailWithError:`

```
// Once the delegate receives this message, it will receive no further messages for connection.
```

So I'd say you have a bug somewhere else in the code. Once that delegate message is called, the connection is done and it will never be restarted unless you do so.

From the question it seems like you are trying to cancel the connection in the failure delegate method, is that correct? That should not be necessary since the connection is already dead. I'm also a bit confused when you say you "retry to quickly". I don't see any "retry" code so it would help if you could post that too.

Can you post more code to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: If I cut the connection and send a message and re establish the connection within a short period of time (a few seconds) the message will still be sent (behavior I do not want). If I wait for longer than 5-10 seconds the message will fail which makes me think there is some underlying mechanism that is retrying the requests for a short period of time.

Comment: I think we're seeing this problem, too. Our NSURLProtocol subclass tries to cancel the connection on an HTTP basic auth failure. But something is retrying the request 5 more times. Maybe Apple developer forums is a better place to ask this question. An Apple engineer might be able to tell us if there is some internal retry mechanism.